# Write the regex pattern for easier understanding/maintenance?

Tags: java, regex

A regex pattern as this:

```
".*/.*/.*/.*/.*/.*/(.*)-\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}.\d{4}.*"
```

is really hard to maintain.

I am wondering, is there something as:

```
".*<userName>/.*<envName>/.*<serviceName>/.*<dataType>/.*<date>/.*<host>/(.*)-\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}.\d{4}.*<fileName>"
```

to help to read/understand the regex more easily?

#### Updated 2018-12-07

Thanks for the help of @Liinux, it's called [free-spacing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html) and a simple java demo would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String re = "(?x)"
            + "# (?x) is the free-spacing flag\n"
            + "#anything here between the first and last will be ignored\n"
            + "#in free-spacing mode, whitespace between regular expression tokens is ignored\n"
            + "(19|20\\d\\d)       # year (group 1)\n"
            + "[-/\\.]             # separator\n"
            + "(\\d{2})            # month (group 2)\n"
            + "[-/\\.]             # separator\n"
            + "(\\d{2})            # day (group 3)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(re);
    Stream.of("2018-12-07", "2018.12.07", "2018/12/07").forEach(aTest -> {
        System.out.println("**************** Testing: " + aTest);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(aTest);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group - " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That pattern looks very broken. Any occurrence of `.*` in a regex is a red flag; 8 of them in a single regex are guaranteed to be a bug.

Comment: x-site duplicate https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194975/readable-regular-expressions-without-losing-their-power

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov so many thanks for the link, it's quite detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add comments in regex using [free-spacing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html), if your language supports it. In free-spacing mode whitespace is ignored (caveats apply) and you can add comments using the `#` sign.

### Example from tutorial

```
# Match a 20th or 21st century date in yyyy-mm-dd format
(19|20)\d\d                # year (group 1)
[- /.]                     # separator
(0[1-9]|1[012])            # month (group 2)
[- /.]                     # separator
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])   # day (group 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Perl, you can just enable the `/x` flag and put whitespace and comments in your regex:

```perl
qr{
    .*  # userName
    /
    .*  # envName
    /
    .*  # serviceName
    /
    .*  # dataType
    /
    .*  # date
    /
    .*  # host
    /
    (.*)-\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}.\d{4}.*  # fileName
}x
```

That said, all of those `.*` should probably be `[^/]*` if that's what you mean (a sequence of non-slash characters).

You could also build up the pattern from variables with sensible names:

```perl
my $userName =
my $envName =
my $serviceName =
my $dataType =
my $date =
my $host = qr{[^/]*};

my $fileName = qr{(.*)-\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}.\d{4}.*};

...
qr{$userName/$envName/$serviceName/$dataType/$date/$host/$fileName}
```